# Is there any alternative to document.form.submit()?

Tags: javascript, submit

I will pass my parameters from input types, to another php file.
I check for empty input texts in a javascript function, and after I will send parameters with an alternative function not with document.form.submit()

**My code:**

```
<script>     
function valida_envia(){ 
    //valido el nombre 
    if (document.fvalida.dni.value.length==0){ 
        alert("Tiene que escribir su DNI") 
        document.fvalida.dni.focus() 
        return 0; 
    } 

    if (document.fvalida.nombre.value.length==0){ 
        alert("Tiene que escribir su nombre") 
        document.fvalida.nombre.focus() 
        return 0; 
    } 

    if (document.fvalida.telefono.value.length==0){ 
        alert("Tiene que escribir su telefono") 
        document.fvalida.telefono.focus() 
        return 0; 
    } 
    if (document.fvalida.email.value.length==0){ 
        alert("Tiene que escribir su mail") 
        document.fvalida.email.focus() 
        return 0; 
    }


    //el formulario se envia 
    alert("FORMULARIO ENVIADO"); 
    document.fvalida.submit(); 

}

</script>
```

Comment: jquery `$("form").submit()`

Comment: get values and submit through ajax or with another dummy form or with window url open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `return` like the code below, you can prevent the form submission by returning `false` from the `validate()` function.

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">

function validate(){
   // Do your stuff here
   return true; // submit the form

   return false; // don't submit the form
}
```

**OR**

You can bind an event handler to the `submit` event (following code assumes you have an `id` on your `form`):

```
document.getElementById("someForm").onsubmit = function() {
    //Do stuff
};
```

Comment: i think i need line like this: 
    <a href="datos.php?dni=dni&nombre=nombre&telefono=telefono&email=email" >Validar</a>

Comment: What do you mean? your question was different.